# Linux FHS & Best Practices

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I'm new to Linux (Ubuntu) and the FHS standard is a little confusing. Also, because its a *standard* and not a strictly-enforced system, I see many applications installing files to the various FHS directories in inconsistent ways.

My first question: **is there a way to force a package to install software under, say, just the `/opt` directory**? That way I could install all of my software nicely underneath `/opt`. My motivation behind this is that I usually cannot find where a binary or any of its resources were installed to, even after reading through the documentation (and browsing the "Installed Packages" list in Synaptic).

My second question: if the 1st question isn't possible (all apps rooted at /opt), then how does the average Linux guru tell where a particular file got installed to. Say I install MySql workbench, which has some `blah.qfx` resource (like an ODBC driver or something)...how do I quickly query my system to see where `blah.qfx` now lives?

Comment: If I am on an unfamiliar Unix/Linux variant i run `man hier`.  This will print a document telling me how files are organized.  `man` pages generally specify where the significant files can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always install to a different directory, but this isn't always advisable imho.  Some packages don't like being installed in other locations.

```
apt-get install something --path=/opt/or-somewhere
```

as far as locating what is where... a large portion of that is using the `locate` command which is part of the slocate package iirc.  `updatedb` to build a database of where files are (which is usually run regularly as a cron job) and `locate something` to actually find it.  If you're simply looking for where an executable is hiding... just use `which` to give you the exact path it's running from.

As far as what is commonly put where... most flavors of linux have their own mind on this subject.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) has a good article on this subject... that is a good place to start.